# Set system date while keeping system time with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have the following Powershell command to set the system date:

```
Set-Date -Date 2015-11-04
```

However this sets the time to 00:00:00 but I need the current time. I thought of something like this but it doesn't work.

```
Set-Date -Date "2015-11-04 (Get-Date).ToShortTimeString()"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to include formatting you can use

```
set-date -date ("2015-11-04 " + (Get-Date).ToString("hh:mm:ss"));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Set-Date -Date ("2015-11-04 " + (Get-Date).ToShortTimeString())
```

Answer (score 1):

`-Date` requires a `DateTime` object and your string is not parsed correctly because of wrong format and lack of subexpression `$()`.

```
[datetime]"2015-11-04 (Get-Date).ToShortTimeString()"
Cannot convert value "2015-11-04 (Get-Date).ToShortTimeString()" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
```

You could use `-Adjust` with a `TimeSpan` object.

```
Set-Date -Adjust ([datetime]"2015-11-04" - (Get-Date).Date)
```

Comment: No? I haven't tested this, but it uses `-Adjust` which uses a timespan-object. And the timespan object generated doesn't modify hours, minutes or seconds.

Comment: Oh, right, I missed that you subtracted the date. Nevermind, then